How to get https working in DRF deployed to AWS Fargate + API GW?
I'm struggling to set up a Django Rest Framework app in AWS to use TLS.
I have an API Gateway v2 proxying requests to an Application Load Balancer that reaches some ECS containers (ECS cluster created via Fargate). API GW is doing the TLS termination and the connection to the LB is in HTTP. The load balancer listens on a different port than 443.
The flow/URLs are like this:
https://api-gw.example.com:443 -> http://lb-internal.foo:1234 -> ecs_containers
This mostly works, except from internal links that are misrepresented. For example, in the root of my DRF API the URLs returned are like http://api-gw.example.com:1234/foo instead of https://api-gw.example.com/foo. This link does not work: wrong protocol and wrong port, but correct URL.
I do have SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https") on my settings.py.
How can I get this setup to work as expected? How to troubleshoot further?
